# Таймер для каждого пользователя из базы данных sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, бот, таймер

Предложим, что в базе данных сейчас два человека (1 строка - VK Id, 2 строка - количество секунд)...
Как сделать так, чтобы у каждого из 2-х людей время двигалось (по -1 за сек)?
То есть, вот у 1 человека - 10 секунд, у второго 30 секунд, у первого прошло 10 секунд - таймер для него остановился, у второго прошло 30 секунд - таймер у него остановился!
Возможно, это можно сделать через модуль `threading`, но я не соображу как?
База данных: `sqlite3`; ЯП - `python`; Библиотека: `vk_api`.

Comment: Я, конечно, не эксперт, но не легче ли завести поле с датой создания таймера / секундами, прошедшими с момента создания unix?

Comment: Можно поподробнее, пожалуйста? Кстати, прошу заметить, что в sqlite3 нет такого типа как дата и время!(это просто, к сведению)

Comment: @Novice, https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Comment: Лучше для начала сформулируйте, что вы хотите в итоге получить, зачем это всё? Может вы вообще другую задачу решаете, но не знаете об этом. Я бы записывал, например, два времени в базу - время старта таймера и время остановки таймера. Но, повторюсь, мне непонятно - зачем это.

Comment: CrazyElf, видел Игровых Ботов в вк? В них присутствуют бонусы, которые можно активировать раз в сутки, хочу это реализовать

Comment: @Novice Просто храните в БД дату, когда команду можно будет использовать снова. Если текущая дата `<` даты в базе, то игнорировать команду, иначе выполнить.